# Encoding in Java

Tags: java, html-entities

I have a string with special characters in Java.

```
"[^\\"]*\\"
```

I want to convert it to HTML entities like this:

```
&quot;[^\\&quot;]*\\&quot;
```

How this could be achieved in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String.replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as needed:

```
"[^\\\"]*\\".replace("\"", "&quot;");
```

Comment: I wasn't allowed to increase the library size. So, chose this method and implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) includes a helper for encoding HTML. [StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)) should do the trick. According to the javadocs it "Supports all known HTML 4.0 entities, including funky accents".

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input string character by character and look for particular ones that you want to convert. When you find a match, simply replace that character with the HTML entity.